# how to search range date in advanced serach

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i use this function to build advanced search with many criteria but when search with time i rain into one problem
how to use between - or (or) condition in only with date

// post inputs

```
$pi_num = $this->input->post('pi_num');
$pi_name = $this->input->post('pi_name');
$pi_passport = $this->input->post('pi_passport');
$pi_date_reg = $this->input->post('pi_date_reg');
$pi_date_reg2 = $this->input->post('pi_date_reg2');
$pi_branch_id = $this->input->post('pi_branch_id');
$pi_gender = $this->input->post('pi_gender');
$pi_importance = $this->input->post('pi_importance');
```

// put it into array
    $conditions = array();

```
if ($pi_num !== '') {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_num LIKE "' . $pi_num . '"';
}
if ($pi_name !== '') {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_name LIKE "%' . $pi_name . '%"';
}
if ($pi_passport !== '') {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_passport = "' . $pi_passport . '"';
}
if ($pi_date_reg !== '') {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_date_reg = "' . strtotime($pi_date_reg) . '"';
}
if ($pi_date_reg2 !== '') {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_date_reg = "' . strtotime($pi_date_reg2) . '"';
}
if ($pi_gender !== '') {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_gender = "'.$pi_gender.'"';
}
if ($pi_importance !== '') {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_importance = "' . $pi_importance . '"';
}
if ($pi_branch_id !== '') {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_branch_id = "' . $pi_branch_id . '"';
}
```

then collect all that with implode function..but i want to use another query condition for date..how to do this?

```
$sqlStatement = 'SELECT
            d_branch.*,
            d_patient.*
          FROM  d_patient
            LEFT JOIN d_branch
              ON d_branch.branch_id = d_patient.pi_branch_id WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions)
;
$result = $this->db->query($sqlStatement);

return $result->result_array();
```

}

this is query example

```
SELECT d_branch.*, d_patient.* FROM d_patient LEFT JOIN d_branch ON d_branch.branch_id = d_patient.pi_branch_id WHERE pi_num LIKE "555555" AND pi_passport = "333333" AND pi_date_reg = "1404684000" AND pi_date_reg = "1405029600" AND pi_gender = "1" AND pi_importance = "1" AND pi_branch_id = "1443"
```

Comment: With dates columns you could use [mysql between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between). No additional brackets required.

Comment: you dont understand my question..how to edit php code to use between with date only

Comment: Just to be clear, you want `pi_date_reg` column to be between `$pi_date_reg` and `$pi_date_reg2`? And tell me what kind of column format is `pi_date_reg`.

Comment: this two fields is jsut one field..i want to search all users registration dates from specified date to another date example from 7/7/2014 to 10/7/2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
if ($pi_date_reg !== '' AND $pi_date_reg2 !== '') {
    $conditions[] = "(pi_date_reg  BETWEEN '" . strtotime($pi_date_reg) . "' AND '" . strtotime($pi_date_reg2)."')";
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the answer I wanted to give him just now. However, those brackets are not required :D

Comment: @machineaddict yup not required, its required for active record though.

Comment: No, it's not required. I'm developing in CodeIgniter and never had the problem you are saying.

Comment: @machineaddict its a case when you have 2 date columns in db to compare and you want to select rows ** condition1 AND condition2 AND (uploaded_on between $d1 and $d2 OR updated_on between $d1 and $d2 )** such query in active records requires brackets. Because without those brackets it would be ** condition1 AND condition2 AND uploaded_on between $d1 and $d2 OR updated_on between $d1 and $d2 ** which provides false result.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant. However, he doesn't require `OR` in his query.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($pi_date_reg !== '') {
  if ($pi_date_reg2 !== '') {
    $conditions[] = '(pi_date_reg BETWEEN "'. $pi_date_reg .'" AND "'. $pi_date_reg2 .'")'; 
  }
  else {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_date_reg >= "'. $pi_date_reg .'"';
  }
}
```

In this way the second date is optional but you can search enyway for all rows with `pi_date_reg >= $pi_date_reg`.
Be sure that format input date is yyyy-mm-dd

Just i way to improve you code security, using placeholders:

```
$conditions = $values = array();
if ($pi_num !== '') {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_num LIKE "%d"';
    $values[] = $pi_num;
}
if ($pi_name !== '') {
    $conditions[] = 'pi_name LIKE "%%s%"';
    $values[] = $pi_name;
}
//...
```

and so on

Then:

```
$result = $this->db->query($sqlStatement, $values);
```